# Datepicker после выбора даты отправить ajax post

Tags: php, javascript, html

знатоки!

Вопрос в следующем:

Имеется инпут, при нажатии который отображает календарь с возможностью выбора даты

```
<div class="col-sm-6" style="padding-right: 3px;">  
<div class="btQuoteItemInput">
<input id="datetimepicker2" name="datetimepicker2" data-open-on="today" type="text">
</div>
</div>
```

Пытаюсь сделать так, чтобы после выбора даты сразу же отправлялся ajax post запрос

Файл, принимающий и передающий в контроллер дату bootstrap.php:

```
$route->post('/gettimes', function () {
    return Application::getPage('index::gettimes');
}, 'ajax');
```

Метод в контроллере, отправляющий данные в модель

```
public function gettimesAction()
   {
       if(isset($_POST)){ 
           $getTime = timestatus::getTimes($_POST['datetimepicker2']);
           echo $getTime;
       }

    }
```

js код, с помощью которого пытаюсь отправить запрос

```
$("#datetimepicker2").on("change keydown paste input",(function(e){

    var text = $("#datetimepicker2").val();

    e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
        url: "/gettimes",
        type: "POST",
        data: text,
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
}));
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализовать это?

Comment: ну дак, а не работает то у вас что?

Comment: @teran при выборе даты (она отображается в инпуте), я не понимаю, как сделать так, чтобы инпут сразу же отправлял запрос, за тем и обратился

Comment: вы какой пикер то используете? они разные бывают.

Comment: @teran   var datepicker = new Datepicker('#datetimepicker2', {
    i18n:{
       months: ["Январь", "Февраль", "Март", "Апрель", "Май", "Июнь", "Июль", "Август", "Сентябрь", "Октябрь", "Ноябрь", "Декабрь"],
       weekdays:["Вс", "Пн", "Вт", "Ср", "Чт", "Пт", "Сб",]
     },
    min: (function(){
      var date = new Date();
      date.setDate(date.getDate() - 1);
      return date;
    })()
    
});

Comment: я не спрашивал, как вы его создаете. я спрашивал какой js плагин вы используете. Этот может https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html  ? или пикер из jquery UI ? или еще какой?

Comment: @teran Datepicker js вроде, не скажу, ибо нашел в интернете, забрал либу и css

Comment: @teran код брал отсюда http://jonthornton.github.io/jquery-timepicker/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> код брал отсюда jonthornton.github.io/jquery-timepicker

по данной ссылке вообще упомянается `timepicker` но есть отсылки к `bootstrap-datepicker`, [упомянутый мною в комментариях](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).

Дак вот для последнего есть событие [`changeDate`](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/events.html#changedate),  срабатывающее при смене даты в календаре.

обрабатывать его следует примерно следующим образом:

```
$("#cal").datepicker({
              .... // настройки
          })
         .on('changeDate', function(){
              var d = $("#cal").datepicker('getDate');   //выбранная дата
              $.post(....)  ; //отправка вашего запрос

         });
```

Comment: Спасибо, попробую